# Equivalent to Dimension from react-native in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, web-applications

Is there an equivalent to Dimension library from react-native in react js for finding the width of the screenspace? If not how could I go about this?

I am trying to find the width of the current webpage so that I can scale my components accordingly, and show/hide certain components depending on the width. An example of the react native code I am trying to use is:

```
{(Dimensions.get('window').width < filterBoxViewWidth) && <div> .. </div>}
```

or:

```
(Dimensions.get('window').width >= filterBoxViewWidth) ? 200 : 0
```

If there is not an equivalent package that I could use, would you please be able to point me in the right direction for how to do this otherwise.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use the Web Api [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.innerWidth` for width and `window.innerHeight` for height. It is supported by all modern browsers:

```
const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window
```

should be equivalent to:

```
const ( width, height } = Dimension.get('window')
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight